# How to show infinite $n$ exist for the following

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $x$ is cube free, it is not divisible by the cube of any prime $p$.

Show that there are infinitely many integers $x$ such that each of the numbers $x, x+1, x+2, x+3$ are not cube free.

How do you write an infinite proof like this?

Comment: Render $x\equiv0\bmod 8, x\equiv-1\bmod 27,x\equiv-2\bmod 125, x\equiv-3\bmod 343$.  Can you solve using the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Answer (score 4):

This is easiest to show via Chinese remainder theorem.

By CRT, there exists a solution $\mod (2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7)^3$ to the system $$x\equiv0\bmod2^3$$$$x\equiv-1\bmod3^3$$$$x\equiv-2\bmod5^3$$$$x\equiv-3\bmod7^3$$Since there are infinitely many numbers congruent to $x\bmod (2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7)^3$, we are done.

P.S. I chose $2,3,5,7$ arbitrarily. Any choice of $4$ integers $>1$ that are pairwise coprime would work just as well.